# Android wait before displaying messagebox

Tags: c#, monodevelop, sleep, wait, toast

I am using MonoDevelop for Android and have a question about waiting x amount of time after showing a Toast and then displaying a Messagebox.

What is the best way to do this?

I have tried the following, with no successful result:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

With the above code, the Messagebox is displayed straight after the toast?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're trying to make something like a delay, I don't know much about androids but I'd think that you could do something like this and it will continue other event while doing so.

```
public void delay(int milliseconds)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, millseconds);
    while(dt > DateTime.Now)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}

public ConstructorNameHere
{
    // Show Toast would go here.
    delay(1000); // Waits for 1 second
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
}
```

I hope this helps. Tell me if it does.